# Chart JS - Data graph is out of chart

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

I m new to chart.js, and yet so far i was unable to find answer for this issue. When i add option to chart scaleBeginAtZero: true, some of the top values is out of Y axis boundaries, and in some cases it shows nice view. Maybe it is something to do with the steps of Y axis ? Note in example how Y axis max value 2560 and data in the graph is 2700. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fivVn.png)

Comment: Please note that graph must begin at zero, and removing that options is, lets say - not an option...